# Why scroll doesn't work in Column? (jetpack compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to make a layout like this:
[image]

The layout is: an image with fixed size and a layout with grey background that should fill the remaining space of the screen. These elements should be scrollable.
Though the layout is quite simple I can't handle it. The reason is that I need to to add .weight(1f) modifier to make grey background fill the rest of the screen, but it disables scroll instead. And vice versa, without this modifier scroll works properly, but grey background doesn't fill the rest of the screen.

I suppose scroll doesn't work because it need to know size of it's content and it doesn't. But I could be wrong. Could you please help me to fix this problem?

```
    @Composable
fun TestCompose(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = Color.White),
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
                .weight(1f)
        ) {

            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                painter = painterResource(id = drawable.check_status_icon),
                contentDescription = null
            )

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f) // This line makes grey background fill the rest of the screen as it is demanded, but disables scroll instead.
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp))
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
            ) {
                // Here are different optional custom layouts inside a column but I left Text only
                Text(text = text)
                AnotherLayout()
            }

        }


        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            onClick = {}){
            Text("Go to main", fontSize = 25.sp)
        }
    }
}
```

Btw if I use `.fillMaxHeight()` modifier instead of `.weight(1f)` the layout wraps content. This is behaviour I don't understand as well:

[image]

Comment: Why not use `fillmaxheight()` modifier ?

Comment: I pasted wrong code. I have edited it now. `.fillMaxHeight()` doesn't fix it -  the layout still wraps content. Btw this is behaviour I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the text has enough height to fill the empty space with below code and update the ui according to it.

```
var textDidOverflowHeight by remember {
    mutableStateOf(false)
}

if (textDidOverflowHeight) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp))
        .background(Color.LightGray)) {
        Text(text = text)
    }
} else {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .weight(1f)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp))
            .background(Color.LightGray)
    ) {
        Text(text = text,
            onTextLayout = {
                textDidOverflowHeight = it.didOverflowHeight
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it may work if there is only Text in the Column. But actually there may be several various layouts in this Column. Using didOverflowHeight here is not enough. I may have missed this in the question, now it is updated